# Inline Styling Individual React Components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to move individual components with inline styles as I want them in different places of the website. Why is this code not working?

```
import "./App.css";
import React from "react";
import Window from "./components/Window";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Window
          id="firstWindow"
          style={{ position: "relative", left: "200px" }}
          number={"1"}
        />
        <Window id="secondWindow" number={"2"} />
        <Window id="thirdWindow" number={"3"} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

this code works in a different section of the app

```
import React from "react";
import "./Window.css";

class Window extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className="square"
        style={{ position: "relative", left: "200px" }}
      >
        {this.props.number}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Window;
```

Comment: It looks like Window is being correctly styled then? The Window from the top snippet is the same as the bottom? The way it's set, all Window will have the same styling. Are you trying to style each Window differently?

Comment: Thats correct, the Window in the bottom is correctly working, but it shifts all 3 of them. I want to shift each peace differently so I wanted to give them each individual inline styles but that doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline style is passed by property name `style`, use it to set style in the component.

```
style={ this.props.style }
```

A demo:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Window
          id="firstWindow"
          style={{ position: "relative", left: "200px" }}
          number={"1"}
        />
        <Window 
          id="secondWindow" 
          style={{ position: "relative", left: "100px" }}
          number={"2"} />
        <Window 
          id="thirdWindow" 
          style={{ position: "relative", left: "10px" }}
          number={"3"} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Window extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className="square"
        style={ this.props.style }
      >
        {this.props.number}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.square {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  float: left;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  margin-right: -1px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 34px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So here's a code sandbox with a working example based on your code-

https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-borg-hd2o4?file=/src/App.js

First of all, you need to be using `position: absolute` if you're going to use `left: 200px`. When it's `position: relative`, there's no effect.

Secondly, a better way to style these is to use the ids you've already created and then pass it as a prop to the component, check out the example.

Thirdly, React class components are on the way out - you should be learning the React function approach first. I recommend https://fullstackopen.com/en/.

Hopefully that all makes sense!

Comment: Thanks! Ill be sure to checkout fullstackopen